# Trying to target child of a parent with subchildren

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, scss-mixins

**Background:**
I have 2 different components constructed in Angular, both video cards. They are both being styled from the same stylesheet using scss. There is a logic as to why there are 2 separate components that perform similar functions, but I haven't explained that as that is not the question

Component One's structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <h4 class="title">Title</h4>
    <img class="image" src="..."/>   
</div>
```

Component Two's structure:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="parent">
           <h4 class="title">Title</h4>
           <img class="image" src="..."/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**
Styles applied to .container>img are showing up on .container>parent>img, and likewise for .container>h4

**Objective**
Style .container>img/h4 and .container>.parent>img/h4 separately such that styles from one do not affect the other

I would not like to use the :has pseudo-class as that is not fully supported. Thank you all for your help

Comment: If i understand it right you dont want the parent to affect both structure is that right? did you try using span? you can separate them using it then see if that will help and call it with a span. if a parent is affecting all the children you can put !important on a particular children that you wanted to call.

Comment: I would love to change the structure of the components but unfortunately, that is set in stone at the moment. So it has to be a CSS solution as of now

Is it as simple as putting the !important keyword?

Comment: Prob yes calling it important should overwrite the existing css. which one do you want to call exactly? if i understand it right .container > .parent > img.image{your css here} should call the img. If h4   .container > .parent > h4.title { your css here}

Answer (score 1):

HTML CODE:

```
<!-- Component One's structure: -->

<div class="container">
  <h4 class="title">Title</h4>
  <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/09/13/33/laptop-2298286__180.png" />
</div>

<!-- Component Two's structure: -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <h4 class="title">Title</h4>
    <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/08/08/44/artificial-intelligence-3382507__180.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution CSS CODE :

```
/* Target subchild of Component One's */
.container .title {
  color: #00ff00;
}

/* Target subchild of Component Two's */
.container>.parent .title {
  color: #ff0000;
}

/* Target both Subchild using class selector*/
.title{
  color:green;
}

/* Target both Subchild using element selector*/
div h4{
  color:gray;
}

/* Target both Subchild using child selector*/
div>h4{
  color:orange;
}

/* Target both Subchild*/
div .title{
  color:blue;
}
```

I hope it will helpful for you. you can take reference from here:
[CSS SELECTOR](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)
[CSS SELECTOR REFRENCE](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)